# SSL_connect over AWS ELB taking time

Tags: openssl, client-server, amazon-elb

I have a client/server application with Elastic Load Balancer sitting in b/w the two. The client connects with the server using a blocking socket. There are a few instances when the following has happened:

1. Client Connects to Server at time X.
2. Client logs show the tcp connection to be established at time X (possibly connected with ELB).
3. Next step is to do SSL_Connect. SSL_Connect is blocking, hence this request
   blocks for around 5 mins (normally it shouldn't even take a second).
4. On server side, I only see the connect succeeding at time X + 5
   (which is when the SSL_connect moves forward).

I don't have access to the AWS ELB logs, so can't really tell what happened b/w the two.

Any clues on what could be going wrong?

Comment: It's not going to be easy to troubleshoot this without the ELB logs.  Why can't you get them?  The only other option is capturing the TCP traffic on the client side to see if anything interesting happens at lower layers after connection is established (like retransmissions)  but that's only going to take you so far.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the logs weren't enabled when this happened, and this is quite difficult to reproduce. Yeah, I'd capture the traffic, if only it was easier to reproduce.

Comment: I have a customer that intermittently reports something similar when hitting one of my APIs, though they don't know anything about the timing of SSL vs TCP.  The requests eventually succeed but the ELB logs, unfortunately, show the request starting at a time that agrees with the app server, and the customer was unwilling to work with me to try to pinpoint the problem... they just increased their timeouts. :(  The delay in this case (iirc) was between 60 and 120 seconds. I've never duplicated it and of course nothing in ELB or the app ever shows such long durations.